# JavaScript returning NaN value

Tags: javascript

I have two ui-slider, and I have a calculation on a slide callback, but it's returning NaN value

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
  $("#amount").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 160000,
      min: 10000,
      max: 400000,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var interest = 0.0325;
        var amount = parseInt(ui.value);
        var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
        $('#currentamount').val(amount);
        $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
  $("#years").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 8,
      min: 1,
      max: 12,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var interest = 0.0325;
       var years = parseInt(ui.value);
       var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
       $('#yearsval').text(years);
       $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
});
```

I also made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kristianladd/w0xayf7t/

The reason why I put it on its slide callback, so that if you slide either of the two, it will calculate.

Comment: use `console.log` to see values of variables in your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply read status from other slider whenever slide is called:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
  $("#amount").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 160000,
      min: 10000,
      max: 400000,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var years = $('#years').slider("option", "value");
        var interest = 0.0325;
        var amount = parseInt(ui.value);
        var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
        $('#currentamount').val(amount);
        $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
  $("#years").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 8,
      min: 1,
      max: 12,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
       var amount = $('#amount').slider("option", "value");
       var interest = 0.0325;
       var years = parseInt(ui.value);
       var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
       $('#yearsval').text(years);
       $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked as a charm. The logic is completely awesome, since it reads value dynamically. Big thanks!

Comment: See the comments on my answer as to why this method is slightly slower.

Comment: yes it is slower than defining global variables but considering he uses only 2 sliders that should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `years` and `amount` outside your callbacks:

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  var years = 8;
  var amount = 160000;
  $("#amount").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 160000,
      min: 10000,
      max: 400000,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var interest = 0.0325;
        amount = parseInt(ui.value);
        var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
        $('#currentamount').val(amount);
        $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
  $("#years").slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 8,
      min: 1,
      max: 12,
      step: 1,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        var interest = 0.0325;
       years = parseInt(ui.value);
       var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
       $('#yearsval').text(years);
       $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
      }
  });
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w0xayf7t/2/

Comment: Or, instead of saving the values in global variables, you can just get the values of the sliders using: `var amount = $('#amount').slider("option", "value");`

Comment: I'd say your first example is better - it reduces the need for two jQuery selectors. Marginally quicker - but quicker by all means :).

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about avoiding storing data in globals when it is already stored as an attribute of the slider. But speed is more important!

Comment: Agreed - although not completely global - the scope is limited to the function passed to `$(document).ready...` - so that's the best place for them to be (since they're not defined on window).

Answer (score 0):

In the one callback you define `amount`, in the other callback you define `years`, but you use both variables in both callbacks.

That's why you get a `NaN`, because not all of the variables used are defined.

Comment: So if I got 2 sliders, and I want to store each slider's value, how can it be done globally?

Answer (score 0):

Year and amount must be declared outside.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
  var amount = 160000;
  var years = 8;
  $("#amount").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 160000,
    min: 10000,
    max: 400000,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      var interest = 0.0325;
      amount = parseInt(ui.value);
      var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
      $('#currentamount').val(amount);
      $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
    }
  });
  $("#years").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 8,
    min: 1,
    max: 12,
    step: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      var interest = 0.0325;
      years = parseInt(ui.value);
      var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
      $('#yearsval').text(years);
      $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1));
    }
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w0xayf7t/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
```

the variable `years` does not exist in this scope.

```
var temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
```

the variable `amount` does not exist in this scope.

So, if you want use the variables `years` and `amount` for calculations, I think you should move them to global scope. Or inside slider, you could get value `years` or `amount` from element, but this is not exactly
Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/thaopv/e28rf6sd/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

`temp1` is using both `amount` and `years` to calculate. You'll have to make it global in order to work correctly. Since this is common code for both callbacks, it's better to extract it as a separate function. Simply

```
function setMonthly() {
    var interest = 0.0325,
        amount = parseInt($('#currentamount').val()),
        years = parseInt($('#yearsval').html()),
        ans = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), - (years * 12)));
    $('#monthly').text(Math.round(ans));
}
```

and call this function from each slide callback. See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w0xayf7t/4/